Why is `CARGO_BIN_EXE_<name>` not present in tests?
When running the below test snippet against the binary with cargo test the environmental variable CARGO_BIN_EXE_<name> is not available.
Example Code
use std::env;

#[cfg(test)]
fn test_pub_sub() {
    let exe_filepath: String = env::var("CARGO_BIN_EXE_pub-sub-learning").unwrap();

    // Start a new process
    let mut sub_command = Command::new(exe_filepath)
        .arg("sub")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("Failed to start pub");

    // ...
}

Error message
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: NotPresent


I was doing a few things wrong.

The tests were unit tests not integration tests. I had make the test an integration test by moving it to the tests directory next to src. Additionally, validate that the target is a binary (not a library).


Files located under the tests directory are integration tests. When you run cargo test, Cargo will compile each of these files as a separate crate, and execute them.

This is the Cargo.toml file that worked. Importantly, the package is setup to run with the entry point in file src/main.rs.
[package]
name = "pub-sub-learning"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
# skipping...


Use env!("CARGO_BIN_EXE_<name>") instead of env::var("CARGO_BIN_EXE_<name>").

This section of the Cargo Targets documentation hinted at the problem (emphasis added).

Binary targets are automatically built if there is an integration test. This allows an integration test to execute the binary to exercise and test its behavior. The CARGO_BIN_EXE_<name> environment variable is set when the integration test is built so that it can use the env macro to locate the executable.

An important note is that printing out the env::vars() is misleading. The env macro has access to env variables that are not in env::vars()!

Another gotcha is to run cargo test from the CLI instead of an IDE.


"This is the Cargo.toml file that worked" - I don't think what you're showing is helpful. It alone doesn't indicate whether you have a binary or library crate at all, and in leu of that will auto-detect based on the existence of lib.rs and/or main.rs.

"The env macro has access to env variables that are not in env::vars()" - the difference between the two is that env! gets environment variables at compile time, whereas the env::vars() gets environment variables at run time.

@kmdreko the cargo file shows that you do not need a [[bin]] section which was a path I was stuck on.

@DanielButler Yes, you do, but cargo automatically adds implicit sections for src/main.rs and src/bin/*[/main].rs

@cafce25 I’ll add that in the answer, but it sounds like you are agreeing. The [[bin]] section isn’t needed.
